# How to use Azure Bicep to deloy existing Logic APP into Another resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, infrastructure, azure-bicep

Question is simple You have an  Logic APP called Onboarding new student
Student can submit the Microsoft Form with their email address and Name
Then the App Logic will put the Form collected user email address and Name into the Share List
So this App Logic is in Azure Resource Group A.
How do I clone the Same App Logic into the Resource Group B using the Azure Bicep
You know clone is always hard especially you have some connector like the Microsoft form and share list

Comment: Do you mean logic app ? Also could you add some punctuation, your question is hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this can be achieved with bicep (alone). With bicep you could replicate the infrastructure, but it would be empty as the logic of you Logic App would not be replicated.

But it seems possible to do this in the Portal.
https://dailydotnettips.com/cloning-azure-logic-app/